# WordPress Site Text Overlaps Sidebar on Smaller Screen Widths

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am helping a client with an issue where the main text overlaps the sidebar on smaller widths, but when it gets small enough, the sidebar goes away. You can see the overlapping text by making the window smaller horizontally. They are using the SimplePress theme. I also looked at the stylesheet.css and found that there are many error indicators, but not sure if these are causing it. One error in the sidebar CSS says: "Using width with padding left can can sometimes make elements larger than you expect."

Any idea what this could be?

**EDIT:**
I am including the relevant before-and-after CSS that fixed this issue, with context as well.

Theme's style.css (before):

```
    #sidebar { float: left; width: 250px; padding-left: 30px; padding-top: 10px; }
    #sidebar .widget { margin-bottom: 30px; float: left; }
      .widget ul { padding-left: 13px;}
      .widget ul li { padding: 3px 0 3px 5px; list-style-image: url(images/bullet.png); }
      .widget ul li a { color: #525252; }
      .widget ul li a:hover { color: #000; }
      .widget h3 { font-size: 24px; color: #000; display: block; background: url(images/widget-line.png) no-repeat bottom left; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
      #search-bar { float: left; }
        #search-bar #searchinput {background: url(images/search-bg.png) no-repeat; width: 175px; height: 35px; border: none; float: left; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; }
    #posts { float: left; width: 640px; padding-right: 40px; }
    #posts_full { width: 960px; }
      #posts_full .post_full { width: 960px; }
      #posts .post { float: left; margin-bottom: 40px; }
        .post .text { float: left; width: 426px;}
        #posts .post .no_thumb { width: 640px; }
```

The last line (line 148 in the style.css file) is what had to be changed:

```
#posts .post .no_thumb { width: 640px; }
```

After:

```
#posts .post .no_thumb { width: 100%; }
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, I had no idea which part of the code needed fixing or if it was a bug with a plugin, etc. However, once I find it, I can add the before and after code to make it more useful for future visitors. I see someone gave me a change below, so if that works I'll show it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 148 of your style.css change the following:

```
#posts .post .no_thumb {
 width: 640px;
}
```

into:

```
#posts .post .no_thumb {
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I changed it in the editor on the backend, but I checked the page source and it's still set as 640px for some reason. Do you know why it wouldn't update the live site?

Comment: Never mind, I cleared the site's cookies and it updated it and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know why this was causing the text to overlap? I'm curious as to what this CSS is affecting exactly

Comment: Glad it worked! The post had a fixed width of 640px, causing it to overflow with the sidebar on smaller sized screens. Changing the width from 640px to 100% keeps it within the left/content side of your website, so it would stop from overflowing.

Comment: Oh I see, so all posts had that fixed width? I was getting hung up on the ".no_thumb" part. What does the .no_thumb mean? Thanks again.